# Bold text with pdflib

Tags: php, pdf, pdf-generation, pdflib

I have a string and I want to put just the date `01/01/2015` in bold. I have done this:

```
$text_dateretour="Date retour:<fontname=Helvetica-Bold>01/01/2015</fontname>";
$p->fit_textline($text_dateretour, 478, 520, "fontsize=10 italicangle=-12 fillcolor=black");
```

but the date value does not become bold.

Thanks for help

Comment: Ok, Put it, What's problem in it ?

Comment: it's not show the 01/01/2015 on blod i show the text with the <fontname...

Comment: Sorry, I can't understand it clearly.. Can you please more specific

Comment: so i need to see 15/05 on bold thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use the `<b>` tag i.e.,

```
$text_dateretour="Date retour:<fontname='Helvetica'><b>15/05</b></fontname>";
echo $text_dateretour;
```

Comment: it's give me that Date retour:<b>15/05</b> the echo because i work on zend php with pdflib

Comment: Ah,, Can you try the given code in empty .php file for instance ?

Comment: so that's my code `$text_dateretour="Date retour:<b>15/05</b>";
      
       
      $p->fit_textline($text_dateretour, 478, 520, "fontsize=10 italicangle=-12 fillcolor=black");`

Comment: I don't know what you use for `$p->fit_textline` but you may try this `$p->fit_textline($text_dateretour, '478', '520', "fontsize='10',italicangle='-12',fillcolor='black'");`

Comment: i don't understand i try this but i have not  15/05 on bold and i see the balise fontname='hel....

Comment: Are you echo this `$text_dateretour` or telling the final result ?

Comment: when i do echo $text_dateretour die() it's gave me Date retour:**bold**15/05 but on the PDF not i don't know why

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78880/discussion-between-sulthan-allaudeen-and-user3791255).

Answer (score 0):

You can always try to use the "fakebold" option. So your optList would be "fontsize='10',italicangle='-12',fillcolor='black' fakebold"